# how to change from castor to JAXB in a project?

Tags: jaxb, castor

How can i transition from Castor to JAXB in an existing project?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of approaches you can take:

**Approach #1 - Retain Domain Classes**

If you are looking to use the same domain objects used by Castor you will need to annotate them with JAXB annotations.  If you are using Castor's mapping file, and continue to use a mapping file you will need to use a JAXB implementation with an equivalent extensions such as EclipseLink MOXy (I'm the tech lead):

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

**Approach #2 - Generate New Classes**

If you used Castor's [source code generator](http://www.castor.org/sourcegen.html) to generate classes from an XML schema you can simply use JAXB's source code generator to generate new classes from the same XML schema.  For an example see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise for your response. But, currently i m working on a very large Enterprise Project under Misys. The Classes i have to work with are so nuch. And in the Entire Project Castor Marshalling and Unmarshalling has been used. Could you please let me know of a plugin Which can directly Generate the XML and read objects from XMl . And how to remove the Castor Version. Thanks in advance, Blaise.